# MONODROID camera preview with opengl overlay

Tags: opengl-es, xamarin.android, android-camera

I have created an augmented reality application using Monodroid and it works fine on a technical basis. However, the graphics I used were drawn on a canvas and are really too slow.

The application is a simple heads-up compass and speed display a-la luke-skywalkers binoculars.

I am trying to get a camera preview going with an openGL translucent/transparent overlay and yes, I have read whats available but its all pure Android SDK / Java.

Does anyone know of a method of getting this effect in C# and Monodroid possibly using the AndroidGameView? Whatever I do I can see one or the other but never both at the same time.

Comment: Ok smart-arse. if its a poorly researched question, how about you do something constructive and point me to the answer instead of just voting it down. I honestly can't find any MONODROID solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unhelpful jerks are a pleasure to work with.
http://bobpowelldotnet.blogspot.fr/2012/10/monodroid-camera-preview-as-opengl.html